# Highcharts scatter external data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I created document with highcharts scatter graph

```
                Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'scatter',
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        enabled: true,
                        text: 'Date of entry'
                    },
                    startOnTick: true,
                    endOnTick: true,
                    showLastLabel: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Values'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: 100,
                    y: 70,
                    floating: true,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
                    borderWidth: 1
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    scatter: {
                        marker: {
                            radius: 5,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    enabled: true,
                                    lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                            pointFormat: 'Dana {point.x} = {point.y}'
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Values',
                    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
                    data: [[167.6, 64.5], [167.6, 72.3], [167.6, 61.4]]
                }]
            });
```

and this works. This code is from documentation page. I get normal scatter data like on this page [Highcharts scatter jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/scatter/)
Now, I created another PHP file that produces me with data I actually need. it is in document highcharts.php and result is this

> [07.03.2017,21000],[07.03.2017,25000],[07.03.2017,33000],[07.03.2017,27000],[07.03.2017,30000],[01.01.2017,700],[11.05.2017,0],[11.05.2017,0],[11.05.2017,0],[11.05.2017,0],

how to connect data to this highcharts.php file? I found some examples but I cannot get it to work. So for start I need this, ONE line of data to show on scatter diagram. I lost few days and just do not get it what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PHP file returns the array presented above, you need to parse it a little bit in order to use it as data array in a scatter series. First of all, dates should be strings. Secondly, you need to use `new Date()` to create Date instance and use `getTime()` to return timestamps. Also, change xAxis type to `datetime`.

API Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0025rsmt/

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful. I have still problem on how to retrieve those data from external file when I correct it in this way you showed me. I tried with this: var json1 = null;
   $.ajax({
    url: 'highcharts.php',
    success: function(output) {
     json1 = output;
     alert (json1);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
     alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
    }
   }); but value is not saved in json1 variable so code in jsfiddle could use it.

Comment: Please, provide me with a demo where you are trying to receive content of the file.

Comment: I managed to do it in jsfiddle also, whole code but it is no working? https://jsfiddle.net/BSheep/tznkhpsp/

Comment: Of course, since answer was not directly what I asked, I could not get it why it does not work. It works when everything is in same file, when I put data in external file it does not work. That is beaciuse when I put your data variable in separate file, all data are as sring so I must use eval function from javascript and then this example works.