# Highcharts change of data does not work

Tags: javascript, php, date, highcharts

When i use this code, that should work

```
        $('#somefieldname').change(function(){

        $('#container').empty();

        var link='highcharts.php';


        var myjson= $.ajax({ 
          url: link, 
          async: false
        }).responseText;

        myjson = myjson.replace("],]", "]]");

        myjson=eval(myjson);

        Highcharts.chart('container', {
          chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
          },
          title: {
            text: ''
          },
          subtitle: {
            text: ''
          },
          xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                    format: '{value:%d.%m.%Y}',
                    rotation: 45,
                    align: 'left'
                },
            title: {
              enabled: true,
              text: 'Date of entry'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
          },
          yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: 'Value'
            }
          },
          legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
          },
          plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
              marker: {
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                  hover: {
                    enabled: true,
                    lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                  }
                }
              },
              states: {
                hover: {
                  marker: {
                    enabled: false
                  }
                }
              },
              tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: ' {point.y}'
              }
            }
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'Value',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: myjson
          }]
        });


    });
```

And I get these data from highcharts.php

> [[new Date("01.01.2017").getTime(), 700],[new Date("07.03.2017").getTime(), 21000],[new Date("07.03.2017").getTime(), 25000],[new Date("07.03.2017").getTime(), 33000],[new Date("07.03.2017").getTime(), 27000],[new Date("07.03.2017").getTime(), 30000],[new Date("11.05.2017").getTime(), 0],[new Date("11.05.2017").getTime(), 0],[new Date("11.05.2017").getTime(), 0],[new Date("11.05.2017").getTime(), 0],]

I get graph with correct dates, graph looks nice, everying ok.

But when I change #somefiledname value and get this data, from highcharts.php I get nothing. Why?

> [[new Date("31.01.2017").getTime(), 195000],[new Date("31.01.2017").getTime(), 225000],[new Date("31.01.2017").getTime(), 245000],[new Date("31.01.2017").getTime(), 185000],[new Date("31.01.2017").getTime(), 239000],[new Date("20.03.2017").getTime(), 1300],[new Date("20.03.2017").getTime(), 3200],[new Date("20.03.2017").getTime(), 2700],[new Date("20.03.2017").getTime(), 4200],[new Date("20.03.2017").getTime(), 1500],]

Data are like this because of this thread here
[Highcharts scatter external data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744759/highcharts-scatter-external-data)

Comment: When  you pass back the values and use eval, you should really be formatting the date on the server before you send it back. That way you wouldn't have to use eval. Instead of trying to use `new Date("XXX").getTime()` in JS, just use PHP's `date` function on the server, and send the date/time values back ready to use. There are other problems too, but this would be a good start for you.

Comment: I used link to the data from this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744759/highcharts-scatter-external-data and it looks like ajax performs fine on 'Somefield' field change event. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/L406kqfh/.